# Significance of date 02/31/2157?

Tags: oracle, date, powerbuilder

I work in a large scale IT support environment.  Twice now we have seen an invalid date of 02/31/2157 being inserted in an Oracle `DATE` column.  So far I have not been able to reproduce this problem, but it appears to be happening occasionally when a user attempts to save '00/00/0000' into the column. I believe the value is originating from a PowerBuilder DataWindow update.

The application uses myriad libraries for all sorts of technologies, so this question may be a bit vague, but...

Has anyone seen the date 02/31/2157 in some established library that Oracle could be defaulting to when some other invalid date is entered?  Perhaps an end-of-time concept analogous to the beginning-of-time date of 1/1/1970?

Comment: What's inserting the data?  Is it like a Java program or Oracle Forms?  It could be happening before the DBMS.

Comment: It's updating from a PowerBuilder DataWindow. Edited the OP to include that info.

Comment: "beginning-of-time date of 1/1/1971" Nitpick: That would be 1/1/1970.

Comment: Fixed. I blame today's date of 1/11/11 for inserting random 1's into all text 1 type today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was a powerbuilder issue.  The field was created in the datawindow as **required**, but was programmatically changed to be **non-required** before saving. So a null value was being saved to a non-null database column, and powerbuilder inserted some dummy date instead of just throwing an error.

Answer (score 4):

From http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i1847"

> Oracle uses its own internal format to
>   store dates. Date data is stored in
>   fixed-length fields of seven bytes
>   each, corresponding to century, year,
>   month, day, hour, minute, and second.

2157-256 = 1901, which seems suspiciously close to a possible epoch of 1/1/1900  (or 12/13/1901 - which is the rollover date for the [Year 2038 Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem))

I'd guess that it is storing either 0x00 or 0xFF in the date bytes, then getting confused when it decodes it.  (How does it deal with month 255?)

Comment: It can be useful to do a SELECT DUMP(date_col) ... to see the individual bytes. It is possible to store invalid dates into a date field (but not easy at the SQL level). When an invalid 7-byte date is returned to a client (such as TOAD or SQL*Plus) it is up to that client to display it, so the same invalid database value may get displayed different ways by different clients.

Comment: This sounds like a possibility, but the application restricts users from entering nonvalid dates.  To be more specific, only a valid date/month combination between 01/01/0001 and 12/31/9999 can be entered. I tried entering several dates obscenely far into the future to try to run into the rollover problem you described, but I have still been unable to recreate the issue.

Comment: To check for the bug I mentioned in my answer, try dates like 2/29/2011. These were not rejected and changed to a strange date. I don't have my notes anymore (really draconian IP agreement, I had to certify that I had _nothing_ from that job when I left).

Comment: I did try several invalid dates by working around the edit mask,  including 02/29/<non-leap-year> and 02/31/2157 specifically. However, our application has a second layer of logic beyond the edit mask  that enforces a valid date before saving. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

I remember getting a weird value when saving an invalid date. IIRC it was in PB 9 and we had to get an EBF for it. It was a problem with Date Editmasks and entering an invalid date that wasn't rejected. Sorry I don't have more details.